# Can't set maximum resolution on an LG Flatron L177WSB 

Tags: intel-graphics, resolution

I have an LG Flatron L177WSB Monitor. My supported resolution is maximum 8192 x 8192 according to the xrandr command. But Ubuntu only allows me to set maximum resolution of 1024 x 768.
I would like to have a resolution of about 1440 x 900 or whatever is best but not 1024x768.

Also Ubuntu doesn't detect my monitor and shows it as "Unknown". I am using Ubuntu 11.04 on Intel i3 with a Gigabyte motherboard and no extra graphics card. It is only whats there on the motherboard.

What can be the cause of this and how should I increase my resolution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set resolution using following command.

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1440x900
```

You have to change VGA1 according to xrander properties of your computer. You can find it by the second line of your xrandr output.

If 1440x900 mode is not in your xrandr you have to manually add it by using the commands below.

`gtf 1440 900 85`

85 is the refresh rate. Then the output would be some thing like this,

```
# 1440x900 @ 85.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 80.33 kHz; pclk: 156.79 MHz
  Modeline "1440x900_85.00"  156.79  1440 1536 1696 1952  900 901 904 945  -HSync +Vsync
```

To add a new mode use the command below with the above output without 'Modline' word

```
xrandr --newmode "1440x900_85.00"  156.79  1440 1536 1696 1952  900 901 904 945  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1440x900_85.00
```

Then to use it type command below.

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1440x900_85.00
```