# Ubuntu 12.04 - LG FlatronLED E1941 - Screen Resolution Issue

Tags: 12.04, resolution, screen

Thanks for your time. I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 from 11.10. My screen resolution is stuck at 1366x786. I have tried setting up higher resolution using xrandr command as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51917/cant-set-maximum-resolution-on-an-lg-flatron-l177wsb) but it is not working.

My [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105822/lg-flatronled-e1941s-how-to-switch-to-highest-resolution) about 11.10 has remained unanswered for the long time and as this is for 12.04, I have created this new question in the anticipation that the problem may be resolved in this LTS version.

Out put of `xrandr` command is as follows:-

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 4096 x 4096
VGA1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 230mm
   1366x768       59.8*+
   1024x768       75.1     75.0     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
   1440x900_75.00   75.0  
   1440x900_74.00   74.0
```

Output of `lspci` is as follows:-

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ/P/PL Memory Controller Hub (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 01)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 01)
01:05.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)
```

Please help,

P.S. What is interesting is WinXP on the same machine is able to see the mode upto 1600x1200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a matter of fact, physical resolution of your monitor is 1366x768, the very first link in google proves this: http://budgetcomputer.co.nz/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=396

With LCD monitors, setting resolution above physical makes absolutely no sense. Whatever Win XP "sees" is a bug - actually, WinXP was created before LCD monitors became mainstream.

Comment: Well, then why does xrandr reports "maximum 4096 x 4096"?

Comment: That's what your video adapter can do. But for monitor, any non-native resolution would result in blurriness and poor image quality because of scaling